# The variable is declared but never used

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a project that is creating a rapid translating program to mess up text using google's API. But I keep running into warning CS0168 and don't know how to fix it. The code is here:

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Translation.V2;

namespace Program
{
    public partial class Translate
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Write text to become cursed");
            string Phrase = Console.ReadLine();

            string TranslateText() //this variable is the problem
            {
                TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();
                //this block repeats with the language changing each time
                var response = client.TranslateText(
                    text: Phrase,
                    targetLanguage: "language",
                    sourceLanguage: "language");
                Console.WriteLine(response.TranslatedText);
                Phrase = response.TranslatedText;
                //end of reapeat
                return response.TranslatedText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I ignore the warning the program wont run.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't run?" Show the complete message the compiler gives you, and explain what happens when you ignore the warning and try to run the program.

Comment: Maybe you can put a Console.Read() in last line forMain function,

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What I mean is the program runs but shuts down when I enter any text. the same thing happens when I ignore it.

Comment: Looks like you declared what looks like a local function called `TranslateText()` (inside of `Main()`) which is never called.

Comment: `string TranslateText()` is a function variable, and the function is just defined, never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with your code:

1. As others have indicated, you declared a local function but you never used it.
2. The application exits right away because it's done all its work. You need to add `Console.ReadLine();` or `Console.ReadKey();` at the end to prevent it from closing.

Try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write text to become cursed");
    string Phrase = Console.ReadLine();

    string TranslateText()
    {
        TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();
        //this block repeats with the language changing each time
        var response = client.TranslateText(
            text: Phrase,
            targetLanguage: "language",
            sourceLanguage: "language");
        Console.WriteLine(response.TranslatedText);
        Phrase = response.TranslatedText;
        //end of reapeat
        return response.TranslatedText;
    }

    string translatedText = TranslateText();
    Console.WriteLine("The translated text is: " + translatedText);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With that being said, a local function might not be the best way to handle this.  Instead, you could move it outside the `Main` and add a string parameter to it so that you can pass the phrase as an argument to it. In this case, your code would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write text to become cursed");
    string phrase = Console.ReadLine();

    string translatedText = TranslateText(phrase);
    Console.WriteLine("The translated text is: " + translatedText);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string TranslateText(string phrase)
{
    TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();
    //this block repeats with the language changing each time
    var response = client.TranslateText(
        text: phrase,
        targetLanguage: "language",
        sourceLanguage: "language");
    Console.WriteLine(response.TranslatedText);
    //end of reapeat
    return response.TranslatedText;
}
```

Comment: Given the question, I am going to guess that the OP is relatively new to C#. As such I'd suggest perhaps showing an option that _doesn't_ use a local function.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the suggestion! Added that to the answer.